# tfpdf -Can't open file C:\webprojects\www\diners/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf

Tags: php

`tfpdf -Can't open file C:\webprojects\www\diners/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf` this file name is from my windows local system? and is displayed when trying to run from the web host.

```
require('tfpdf.php');
class PDF extends tFPDF {
    function Header(){
        global $title;
        // Select Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(20);
        // Framed title
        $this->Cell(150,10,$title,1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
}
// Which pdf are we going to produce
$report=$_POST['report'];
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','B','DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf',true);
//$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$jmcFont='Times';
switch($report) { 
    case "list":
    $pdf->SetFont($jmcFont,'B',14);$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Diners');$pdf->Ln(10); 
    foreach($diners as $d) {
        if ($d['attending']==1) {
            $x=explode('|',$d['menuchoice']);  
            $pdf->SetFont($jmcFont,'B',10);
            $pdf->Write(5, $d['fname'].' '.$d['sname'].':-');
            $pdf-setfont($jmcFont,'',10);
            $pdf->Write(5, $starter[$x[0]].'-'.$mains[$x[1]].'-'.$sweet[$x[2]].'Note:'.$d['apology']);
            $pdf->Ln(7);           
        }
    }
```

The code works fine if the

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','B','DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf',true); 
    lines are commented out.
```

**Why is it trying toreference my windows system?**

Answer (score 11):

There is an internal cache in the project. At first runtime the program saves path to the font, in Dejavu font case it is `DejaVuSansCondensed.mtx.php`:

```
$ttffile='/Users/user/WebstormProjects/php/pdf/tfpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf';
```

This is a big problem and wise developers should avoid such scenarios, as your local configuration can appear in production. 
For a fast solution just delete `*.mtx.php` files before publishing or never commit them to your source repository.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Saved me a fair amount of time.  My solution was to replace the line with :  $ttffile=str_replace(".mtx.php",".ttf",__FILE__);

Comment: Saved me a lot of time too, just deleted the .mtx.php file and everything worked again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I had the same problem. My solution:

Open every `mtx.php` file.

Replace the line (absolute path):

```
$ttffile='D:\xampp8\htdocs\test\include\tfpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf';
```

With (relative path):

```
$ttffile='include/tfpdf/font/unifont/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf';
```

Answer (score 0):

The link is inside the generated font file DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.mtx.php and DejaVuSansCondensed.mtx.php After removal of the windows reference all works fine.